# Converting curl header format to Ruby's header format

Tags: ruby, http, curl, header, get

I am trying to convert this request header into Ruby format:

```
curl http://example.com/api/v1/info -H 'Authorization: Token token="asklasjqwAiSo1s2dj5ias23dkl"'
```

I am trying to add it to an HTTP GET request:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(endpoint, 80)
http.get(path, authorization_header_with_token)
```

How would I build the header I used in the cURL request to work with the Ruby request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header hash parameter should look like this:

```
http.get(path, {'Authorization' => 'Token token="asklasjqwAiSo1s2dj5ias23dkl"'})
```